# Automatically assign a specific user group and modules to a new user

Tags: content-hub, user-profile

I want to automatically assign a specific user group and modules to a new user. I was able to successfully assign the user group with DefaultUserGroups property, but I can't find how to assign the modules. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: this will be helpful https://timmarsh.co.uk/2023/02/17/sitecore-content-hub-assigning-modules-to-a-user-programmatically-on-sign-in/

Answer (score 0):

By creating a [User Sign-In](https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/developers/42/cloud-dev/scripting-api--user-sign-in-example.html) script you can automatically assign modules when a user logs in

The below code is a rough attempt to automatically add the modules, this was just something to prove the concept.

```
var user = Context.User;
await user.LoadMembersAsync(null, new RelationLoadOption("ModuleToUser")).ConfigureAwait(false);
List<long> groups = new List<long>();
groups.Add(10464); // M.AssetType.Product
groups.Add(10460); // M.AssetType.Media
groups.Add(10463); // M.AssetType.Print
user.GetRelation("ModuleToUser").SetIds(groups);
// update the user
await MClient.Entities.SaveAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This user sign-in automatically assigns the modules to the user. This code was to test out the concept and confirm we could update the modules.

Follow the blog for more details - https://timmarsh.co.uk/2023/02/17/sitecore-content-hub-assigning-modules-to-a-user-programmatically-on-sign-in/